# Solution to generate invoices on monthly basis automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron, billing

What is the solution to generate invoices every 2 weeks **automatically**? Cron Jobs?

I have multiple orders in the tbl_order table, I want to generate an invoices for every 2 weeks (for billing).

```
    - tbl_order table
    OrderID (PK)
    ShopID (FK)
    CustomerID (FK)
    Status
    Total
    OrderDate

    - invoice table
    InvoiceID (PK)
    InvoiceDate
    InvoiceStatus

   - invoiceorder 
     invoiceorderID (PK)
     InvoiceID (FK)
     OrderID (FK)
```

The invoice date for Feb would be: 01 - 15 February, 16 - 28 February

and on March: 01 - 15 March, 16 - 31 March

So for example, generate invoice between 01 - 15 March on `tbl_order.ShopID = 5`

How can that be done if using Cron Jobs / PHP or alternative solution?

Comment: If the question is _really_ about "generating invoices" from a database, then it's *way* out of scope for SO.  If what you really mean is "how do I run a process (which exists, or which I will write) on a given schedule" then the question is appropriate for superuser.com.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign cron task, use tutorial like this:

http://www.thefactory.ro/php-cron-tutorial

Next, in PHP handler query database for every order that was in that time range and create report based on your needs.

Comment: Is it normal to assign cron task to generate an invoices? Or could the website system design differently that will automatically add into invoice table when user placed an order?

Comment: It is normal to do anything with cron tasks - they are to use them for your needs. PHP don't have its server like Ruby or Python - it's request based, so cron is the only option if you want something to be done not on request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on *nix, you should use cron - [`man crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/).

If you wanted to run the job on say the 1st and 15th of every month @ midnight you would use:

`0 0 1,15 * *`

Answer (score 0):

It goes without saying generally but I will say it anyway. Don't forget to save the invoice data in a separate table of your database for historical look up/tax purposes. This way you can store an invoice number and other variables such as paid and any discounts being applied.

Comment: Invoice numbers and payment status? Are they required over there? In most countries it is seen as best practice to include this info on an invoice.

Comment: I think there is no need to put Invoice Number in the tbl_order, I do have payment status in the tbl_order  table

Comment: As long as the tax man doesn't need them it doesn't really matter! hehe